# How do I complete the Montreal mission without killing any guards?

Tags: achievements, deus-ex-human-revolution

I can't figure out how I could complete the Montreal mission without killing guards. They all stay together so if I stun one they wake him back up. I tried a YouTube search but didn't see anyone do it there either.  Any tips?

The only thing I could think was to use invisibility a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the part where they've dispatched many Belltower agents who are on constant alert.  I found that liberally abusing the vents allowed me to get to areas where they weren't as dense, or weren't able to spot me while I was flanking them.  I did it with very little cloaking, although I also had the tranq sniper rifle and quite a few darts.

Even if there are two together, you can usually shoot one, reload, and shoot the other before he has a chance to alert other guards or wake the first guard up.

If you can, try to move the sleeping guards quickly into an area where none are patrolling, although this can get tricky in some of the more dense areas.  Going cover to cover and avoiding them altogether might be a better strategy in certain parts.  This was one part of the game where I found it tricky to employ a "no witnesses" strategy without resorting to murder.

If you get stuck, cloaking can be a useful strategy.  Make sure you check the various rooms to find additional power restoring food to keep your cloak and melee takedown energy full.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's the hardest part of the game to do non-lethal - there's an optional "save a friend" section I think that comes later which is just god awful hard.  There's also a part where they'll encourage you to go and get a chip replaced - do *not* do this, as it makes a later boss fight so much harder...

Comment: Oh, I'd also suggest taking the Typhoon system for boss fights - you can't use it except for there, but it makes the bosses quite a bit easier.  If you've got Praxis points for it and can stockpile ammo, do so.

Comment: I had this weird situation that I was hiding in one of the offices and a guard comes in. I knock him out, then more keep coming one by one. I ended up with a huge pile of them in there because they were all attracted to that room for some reason.

Comment: @CyberSkull where you detected by a hack on a computer in that office by any chance?  That usually alerts the guards and they'll go investigate that machine.

Comment: I do not recall, but I do not think that to be the case. As I recall there was no alarm, and each was coming one at a time.